# How to use the result of two columns within same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I have a table with such kind of data in 2 columns:

```
TypeOfFruits | Production2014 |
Mangoes         450
Mangoes         100
Berries         50
Berries         75
Mangoes         45
Berries         25
```

My question is: How can I query the data from those two columns so that I can get a result in new columns like:

```
production2014 for Mangoes | production2014 for Berries
450                          50
100                          75
45                           25
```

Comment: How many different `TypeOfFruits` could be possible ?

Comment: There is just Mangoes and Berries!

Answer (score 0):

Using `PIVOT`,`UNPIVOT` in mysql would achive what you want.

Here I found an old discussion about using PIVOT properly,

[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

and here;
http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Comment: oh ...lemme look through that! #Thanks